# Make content active upon select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Are you able to make other content active or visible upon selecting another item, similar to that of the apple iphone webpage - when you select the iphone 4 colour the model version becomes fully visible and active.

[Apple iPhone Page](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone/iphone4s?mco=MjU5MTk4NzE)
How would you go about making this work in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `click` event handler to an element, and do whatever you like in there:

```
document.getElementById("someElem").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("anotherElem").style.display = "block";
}
```

You can see above that I've used the the `style` property, which can be used to change the CSS properties of the element (in this case, I'm changing the `display` property to `block` - if it was `hidden` before then this would make `anotherElem` become visible).

To do that in jQuery:

```
$("#someElem").click(function() {
    $("#anotherElem").show(); //Or use .css to change other CSS properties
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't quite understand what you are getting at here? What exactly is the first piece of code doing?

Comment: The first piece of code is doing the same as the second, just with actual JavaScript rather than jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The `opacity` CSS property is used to "disable" the element. `opacity` takes a value between zero and one - Choosing a value close to zero results in not-so-visible content.

In JQuery, you can achieve this effect by using:

```
$("$myElement").css("opacity", "0.5");
```

At the apple page, the effect is emphasized by adding borders (where they previously didn't exist).